# How to force portrait orientation in NativeScript 8.x for iOS and Android

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

There are a few community plugins that made for this, but none of them support NativeScript 8.x. They utilize "tns-core-modules" rather than "@nativescript/core". I've only found one paid plugin that supports NativeScript 8.x.

Is there truly no way to force portrait orientation natively in NativeScript? If not, it seems like a major oversight for a framework dedicated to making mobile apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to update your `AndroidManifest.xml` & `Info.plist` in your `App_Resources`.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

Set screenOrientation to portrait on your main activity

```
<activity android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptActivity" 
 ... 
 android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

**Info.plist**

Keep only the portrait orientation, remove rest from UISupportedInterfaceOrientations.

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
  <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
</array>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
<array>
  <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
  <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
</array>
```

**Note:** Make sure you run a clean build after these changes.